# Как изменить предмет валидации checkbox'а в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте. Сделал форму используя ActiveForm.
Добавил checkbox вот так:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'budget_agreement',
    ['options' => ['tag' => 'span'],
        'template' => "{input}"]
            )
          ->checkbox(['checked' => true]);
 ?>
```

В модели в rules написал вот так:
    `[['budget_agreement'], 'required']`

И все работает, только наоборот: мне надо чтобы чекбокс был обязательным, и пока он неактивен - форма не сабмитилась. А сейчас получаеться вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы валидатор ругался на неотмеченый чекбокс, а отмеченый пропускал? Спасибо.

Comment: Вероятно есть смысл использовать отдельный метод для валидации.

Comment: Ну, я сделал чекбоксы в модели не обязательными, а валидацию написал на jQuery. Странно почему это так проблемно реализуемо через ActionField.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указать в правиле *requiredValue*: 
`[['budget_agreement'], 'required', 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => 'Подтвердите согласие'],`